# Highest-weight module over $\mathfrak{sl}_2$

Tags: lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras, kac-moody-algebras

I'm reading the following example, which I have trouble understanding:

> Let $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{sl}_2$ and $\lambda=m\Lambda_1$. Consider the irreducible module $V$. Then the vectors in the representation are $\{v,fv,\cdots,f^mv\}$ with weights $\{\lambda,\lambda-\alpha_1,\cdots,\lambda-m\alpha_1\}$

It's not hard to show that the vectors have corresponding weights as described above. I'm assuming we think of $V$ as a highest-weight module with highest weight $\lambda$, but what are $\Lambda_1$ exactly? What importance does $\lambda=m\Lambda_1$ have upon determining the weights and corresponding vectors as described above?

My guess is that $\lambda=m\Lambda_1$ has something to do with $f^{m+1}v=0$ so the vectors and corresponding weights are exactly as stated above. However this is not clear to me, if it's the case.

I should mention that this example is thought of in the setting of Kac-Moody algebras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, $\Lambda_1$ is not a random element of $\mathfrak h^*$. It is a very specific element of $\mathfrak h^*$: it's the only linear form $\Lambda_1\colon\mathfrak h\longrightarrow\Bbb C$ such that$$\Lambda_1\left(\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}\right)=1.$$

Comment: Why does $\Lambda_1$ specifically need to satisfy the relation you mention? What would go wrong if we picked any other element of $\mathfrak{h}^*$?

Comment: If you had picked, say $\Lambda_1\left(\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{smallmatrix}\right]\right)=2$, then there would be no $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $m\Lambda_1\left(\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{smallmatrix}\right]\right)=1$ and so you would never get the $2$-dimensional irreducibel representation of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$.

Comment: $\Lambda_1$ is a fundamental root? I'm thinking that $\lambda=m\Lambda_1$ should play some role in preventing that $h(f^{m+1}v)=(\lambda-(m+1)\alpha )(h)(f^{m+1}v)$ - why is that the case?

Comment: No. Actually, $\Lambda_1$ is not even a root. The roots of $(\mathfrak{sl}_2,\mathfrak h)$ are $\pm2\Lambda_1$.

Comment: Okay. But I guess that $m\Lambda_1$ must somehow determine the dimension of $V$ (forcing $\dim(V)=m+1)$. How does $\Lambda_1$ do so?

Comment: Yes, the dimension of $V$ is $m+1$, but I do not understand your question, in the sense that I have no clue about what it *means*.

Comment: Why is the dimension $m+1$? My thoughts are, tha tif the highest weight were $\lambda=k\Lambda_1$ then the dimension would be $k+1$, but as $\lambda=m\Lambda_1$ then $\dim(V)=m+1$.  How does $\lambda=m\Lambda_1$ force the dimension to be $m+1$?

Comment: The dimension is $m+1$ because a basis of the representation is $\{v,fv,\ldots,f^mv\}$, which has $m$ vectors.

Comment: Why isn't $f^{m+1}v$ a basis vector of the representation? I'm thinking it must have something to do with the highest weight $\lambda=m\Lambda_1$, or I might be totally misunderstanding it. Sorry for the many questions.

Comment: Because $f^{m+1}v=0$.

Comment: Why is $f^{m+1}=0$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120378/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-njlieta).